# CakePHP calling field() within the model

Tags: cakephp

I am writing a function within the php of the model. Is there any issue with using

```
$this->field('something)
```

while inside the model? I can use other things like $this->saveField(...) fine but for some reason this is not returning me the value in the table correctly. Just wanted to make sure, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the conditions first, like so:

```
$this->field('field_name', $conditions);
```

Or, I think you can also try setting the id first

```
$this->id = $id;
$this->field('field_name');
```

Comment: yeah, I tried setting the ID first, and it works fine for everything else except field() for some reason

Comment: what's the output you're getting? Also, if you see here: http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/model/#line-1147, it shows setting the $id is equivalent to setting the conditions (in v1.3).

Comment: apologies, I found the problem--there was a virtual field with the same name that was intercepting the request